# Use devise views with users controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using devise for user management. I've already customised devise views and I'm happy with them. However, when an user wants to edit her profile she will go to `/users/edit`, which is fine. But when an administrator wants to view the profile of that user (other users can't see each other's profile), she would go to `/users/2/edit` (assuming 2 is the id of that user). I would like to use the very same view from devise (located in `/app/
views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`), not a separate one in `/app/views/users/edit.html`.

I could factor out the content in devise view in a partial, but I don't know how to supply the `resource` and `resource_name` (and maybe other)  variables.

This must be a duplicate but I lack the vocabulary to search for a proper answer.

---

routes.rb (wrong as per [devise faq](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface), i think; don't copy-paste!):

```rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ro/ do
    devise_for :users
    resources :users, :only =>[:index, :edit]
end # scope "/:locale"
```

The routes are as follows:

```
                    home GET    (/:locale)/home(.:format)                static_pages#home {:locale=>/en|ro/}
        new_user_session GET    (/:locale)/users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new {:locale=>/en|ro/}
            user_session POST   (/:locale)/users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create {:locale=>/en|ro/}
    destroy_user_session DELETE (/:locale)/users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy {:locale=>/en|ro/}
           user_password POST   (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create {:locale=>/en|ro/}
       new_user_password GET    (/:locale)/users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new {:locale=>/en|ro/}
      edit_user_password GET    (/:locale)/users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit {:locale=>/en|ro/}
                         PUT    (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update {:locale=>/en|ro/}
cancel_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel {:locale=>/en|ro/}
       user_registration POST   (/:locale)/users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create {:locale=>/en|ro/}
   new_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new {:locale=>/en|ro/}
  edit_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit {:locale=>/en|ro/}
                         PUT    (/:locale)/users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update {:locale=>/en|ro/}
                         DELETE (/:locale)/users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy {:locale=>/en|ro/}
             user_unlock POST   (/:locale)/users/unlock(.:format)        devise/unlocks#create {:locale=>/en|ro/}
         new_user_unlock GET    (/:locale)/users/unlock/new(.:format)    devise/unlocks#new {:locale=>/en|ro/}
                         GET    (/:locale)/users/unlock(.:format)        devise/unlocks#show {:locale=>/en|ro/}
                   users GET    (/:locale)/users(.:format)               users#index {:locale=>/en|ro/}
               edit_user GET    (/:locale)/users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit {:locale=>/en|ro/}
                         GET    /:locale(.:format)                       static_pages#home
                         root   /                                        static_pages#home
```

---

User model:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
    attr_accessible :id, :name, :email, :password, 
        :password_confirmation, :remember_me
    as_enum :usertype, :regular => 0, :admin => 1, :superadmin => 2
    before_validation :make_superadmin
    def adminkind?
        return (self.usertype_cd == User.admin) || 
            (self.usertype_cd == User::superadmin)
    end
  private
    def make_superadmin
        if User.count == 0
            self.usertype_cd = User.superadmin
        end
    end
end
```

---

Users controller:

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json {
                render json: UsersDatatable.new(view_context) }
        end
    end
    def edit
    end
end
```